# How to make mysql_read_default_group in perl DBI work

Tags: mysql, perl, ini, dbi, dbd

I am trying to connect mysql using my.ini file as configuration.

Here is my Perl code:

```
use DBI;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:umls;mysql_read_default_group=client;";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn);
```

And here is **my.ini** file:

```
...

[client]

host=localhost

user=root

password=mypassword

database=umls

port=3306

....
```

According to the official document(http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.033/lib/DBD/mysql.pm),
the DBI will use information from my.ini to connect mysql,However,it give me error like:[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z56X3.png)

I think the problem is the DBI never read my.ini successfully so it use ODBC@localhost as a default instead.

The connection will work if I just specify the user name and password inside connect().
Can anyone help me figure out why `'mysql_read_default_group=client'` does not work?
I will be much much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: 1) What operating system is your Perl script running on? 2) What is the full path to your my.ini file? 3) Does the user running the script have permission to read my.ini? 4) Can you please [edit] the full contents of my.ini into your question?

Comment: Did you try to specify the file as well with ```mysql_read_default_file=...```

Answer (score 0):

I read some documents to answar your problem and what I found is that you need to provide the username and password in different section and you need to mention the file name also. like

```
[myapp]
host=localhost

user=root

password=mypassword

database=umls

port=3306
```

then

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:test"
    . ";mysql_read_default_file=$ENV{HOME}/.my.cnf"
    .';mysql_read_default_group=myapp',
    undef, 
    undef
   ) or die "something went wrong ($DBI::errstr)";
```

Hope this will help you.

Reference:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=519356

Comment: Thank you for your response.However,that won't work for me.The fact is I have an CPAN package called UMLS::interface.when installing that module,such error raises.I checked the package source code and it written in following way:
        my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:umls;mysql_read_default_group=client;";
        $db = DBI->connect($dsn);

Comment: So in order to Install that Package,I have to figure out why thIs line of code $dsn = "DBI:mysql:umls;mysql_read_default_group=client;"; $db = DBI->connect($dsn);  dose not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would answer given that there is no module-specific answer. I also experience this error with the UMLS::Interface module and was able to fix it.

The reason you are experiencing this error is because the DBI module is not recognizing that you have set a default UMLS database name in your my.cnf file. If this happens, the authors of the UMLS::Interface module expect there to be a database named 'umls' (case sensitive). In my case, the database was called 'UMLS'.

Two solutions to this problem:

**Solution 1) Edit the UMLS::Interface CuiFinder.pm script**

Go to your UMLS Interface Installation Directory

```
#Location on Ubuntu 22.04
cd /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/UMLS/Interface
sudo nano CuiFinder.pm
#Ctrl + W
#Ctrl + T 
#Enter 2464, which will send you to line 2464
#Enter user password
```

Here you will see a line of code that reads:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:umls;mysql_read_default_group=client;"
```

This is the code excecuted when the my.cnf in your mysql setup is not recognized or there are no client settings (See solution #2). Here, you need to change 'umls' to your db name. In my case, I had created my db with the name 'UMLS', so in my case the line now reads:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:UMLS;mysql_read_default_group=client;"
```

You should now be able to complete the script without errors.

**Solution 2) Edit your mysql my.cnf client settings**
After reading your post further, I noticed you already had edited your .ini file, so it appears solution 1 may be the best bet for anyone trying to get this to work.

Instead of altering the perl code in the UMLS:Interface module, you can also try to get the DBI module to recognize that your default DB is the UMLS database. I was unable to get this to work on Ubuntu 22.04 running mysql Ver 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04. DBI insisted that I did not have a default database, which is weird because it recognized the default user and password in order to access the DB .

Go to your my.cnf file location.

```
cd /etc/mysql
```

Edit the my my.cnf file (note this is read only by default)

```
sudo nano my.cnf
```

Copy and Paste the Following in the file:

```
[client]
user=<your username here>
password=<your user's password>
port=3306 #this is the default but can also check this in mysql with SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%port%;'
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock #this is the default but can also check this in mysql with 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%socket%;''
database=<your database name>
```

In theory, this should allow the CuiFinder.pm script to execute the first clause of the if else statement and pull in your default database without editing the perl code. Like I said, DBI did not recognize this.